# Where is this photo of a bridge located exactly?

Tags: locations

I know [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0TK5.jpg) was taken somewhere in East Coast, but can someone tell me where it is exactly?

[image: this photo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Benjamin Franklin Bridge; crosses the Delaware River. Connects Camden, New Jersey to to Philadelphia, Pennsylvania.

That bus is about to enter Philly, judging from this vantage.